# haproxy 1.8 sc0_get_gpc0 activate acl from bad request count

Tags: load-balancing, acl, haproxy

I'm running HAproxy 1.8 and trying to track a general counter with a stick-table, but each time it's called by the ACL it isn't returning true.

My expectations are; once the counter goes above 5 the ACL will cause it to go to a different backend. What could be going wrong?

```
# default block configs are set to http settings

frontend my_service
  bind *:80
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s

  acl bad_request sc0_get_gpc0(my_service_bk) gt 5
  use_backend my_service_bad_bk if bad_request

  default_backend my_service
backend my_service_bad_bk
  errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/429.http
backend my_service
  http-request track-sc0 req.fhdr(X-My-Service)
  http-response sc-inc-gpc0 if { status gt 399 }
  stick-table type string len 350 size 10m expire 10m store gpc0

  balance roundrobin
  server .....
  server .....
```

I look up the stick-table stats and it shows this after 6 requests:

```
0x7f2279cdsa42: key=test use=0 exp=278850 gpc0=6
```

And it still sends it to the wrong backend (`my_service`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the `stick-table` and `acls` around I came up with a solution. It appears the `sc0_get_gpc0` can get the proper content from the `stick-table` when in a `backend`

Here is what the working code looks like:

```
# default block configs are set to http settings

frontend my_service
  bind *:80
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s

  http-request track-sc0 req.fhdr(X-My-Service)
  stick-table type string len 350 size 10m expire 10m store gpc0

  default_backend my_service
backend my_service
  http-response sc-inc-gpc0 if { status gt 399 }

  acl bad_request sc0_get_gpc0(my_service) gt 5
  use-server bad_request if bad_reqest

  balance roundrobin
  server bad_request localhost:9090 weight 0

  # normal app servers below this without weight 0
  server .....

frontend bad_requests
  bind localhost:9090

  default_backend my_service_bad

backend my_service_bad
  errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/429.http
```

The key to doing it in the backend is using `weight 0` for servers that just provide the error code and response. Servers with `weight 0` won't be used for traffic if the ACL isn't activated.